# Android 13 Splash Screen icon not showing when opened with widget

Tags: android, kotlin

Component used: androidx.core:core-splashscreen
Version used: 1.1.0-alpha01
Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Android 13

Hi,

When I start the application normally, I can see the SplashScreen and the icon successfully and have no problems. But when I want to start the application by clicking a button on the widget, the icon does not appear in SplashScreen.

My SplashScreen Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Start" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
// Set the splash screen background, animated icon, and animation duration.
<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/color_primary</item>
// Use windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon to add either a drawable or an
// animated drawable. One of these is required.
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_splash_foreground</item>
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_launcher_splash_foreground</item>
// Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen.
<item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp.PreLogin</item>
<item name="android:windowSplashScreenBehavior">icon_preferred</item>
</style>
```

installSplashScreen:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
installSplashScreen()
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.NoActionBar"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">


        <activity
                android:name=".ui.authentication.AuthenticationActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.Start"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

 

                <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

        </activity>
</application>
```

My Widget Code:

```
val notificationIntent = Intent(context, AuthenticationActivity::class.java)
    notificationIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

    val notificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, 0, arrayOf(notificationIntent), flags)
    val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.app_widget_currency).apply {

        setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_payment, notificationPendingIntent)
    }
    val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(
        appWidgetIds,
        R.id.widget_mainView
    )
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews)
```

I tried the last 3 versions of SplashScreen libraries, including Alpha.
I changed the icon.

positive result